# discord py give role to specific user id

Tags: discord.py

py API, I want to create a code that can give role to a specific user id that I gave. this is my code, the "userid" variable contain an integer data of the id of one of the member, anyone knows how to add role to the given user id member?

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
for number in range(len(data_dict["username"]) - 1):
    if data_dict["year_start"][number] == year_now and data_dict["month_start"][number] == month_now and data_dict["date_start"][number] == date_now:
        userid = int(data_dict["username"][number])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Kho!

First, get your `Role`

```
my_role = discord.utils.get(context.guild.roles, name="myRole")
```

Then get the `Member` by id, you already have it! (Note: you may need to set the [Intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Client.intents) in your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), if your bot is used in over 100 server, you may need a discord white-list). If you don't want to use Intent, try give a role through `context`.

```
target_member = guild.get_member(userid)
```

Finally, give the role to the member.

```
target_member.add_roles(my_role)
```

Comment: how to set the intent tho?

Comment: @JonathanKho [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) > Applications > your Application(yout bot) > bot > Privileged Gateway Intents > check the two intents

Comment: can I just get the role by defining the role id?

Comment: @JonathanKho Yes, use `id=roleID` instead of `name="myRole"`

Comment: does the context must be defined?

Comment: @JonathanKho Not really, but using context will make it much easier to fetch the role/member in it. or you can use `Client.get_guild` but much complicated. See [API doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Client.get_guild) for more info.